# Is responders suit change after 1NT rebid by opener forcing? (System: simplified SAYC)

Tags: bridge

Auction: 1C - 1H - 1NT - ? (opener has 3 hearts, 12 pts ; responder has 5 hearts, 13 pts)

In case of responder having 13+ pts yet lacking NT distribution, how does partnership get to game with 13+13 total points and 3+5 major fit, after 1NT rebid by opener?

P.S. This is an unfinished question, I might edit it in the future to further elaborate my inquiry on partnership getting to game with 12+13 points by both partners and 1nt rebid by opener.

P.S.2. The inquiry is about the very basics, as this page says: http://larryco.com/BridgeArticles/ArticleDetails.aspx?articleID=462 -- paraphrasing: "The worst mistake I see: Not reaching game when there is enough for game.  If your partner opens the bidding and you have 14 points, please don't ever make any bid which your partner can pass"

Comment: Why is your partner not rising to 2H with that hand? If a real partner failed to reveal 4-card in that auction I'd be promptly looking for a new partner.

Comment: To continue that quote: "You must know which bids are forcing (partner can't pass) and which are non-forcing (partner is allowed to pass). "

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *Simplified* SAYC. SAYC is already very simple and intended as a beginner system. Once you change it, you need to precisely define how you have changed it, or link to a fully filled out convention card.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens you are correct the actual hand I played had 3 + 5 fit, with 4+4 opener would have rebid 2H. My mistake. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.bridgeguys.com/pdf/SAYC.pdf) outlines the system behind SAYC in fairly simple terms. The bottom of page 7 notes that on the auction of interest, responder must reverse or jump shift to create a *game force*. However, a simple new suit bid should be treated as a one-round force, 10+, game invitational.

Most established partnerships now play some form of either [Check Back Stayman (CBS)](http://www.bridgehands.com/C/Checkback_Stayman.htm) or [New Minor Forcing (NMF)](http://www.bridgehands.com/N/New_Minor_Forcing.htm). Both of these are predicated on the requirement that Opener's 1NT rebid categorically denied 4-card support for Responder's major suit response.

If partner rebid 1NT over your 1H response with 4-card Heart support, rightly take that as a gross insult to your card-play. Find a new partner promptly , before this one ruins your bidding.

Answer (score 0):

I think New Minor Force is the best bid to go with i.e 1D which clearly tells partner that I have a 5 carder heart, do you have 3?

Comment: Suggesting that OP play a different system fails to answer the question for the system he ***is*** playing.

Answer (score -1):

If i'm playing with an amateur partner using just the simplest system ever, then I would bid 2S. This bid promises 5-card hearts, at least invitational values (10+ points) and it is forcing. Have in mind that 1NT rebid by opener denies 4-card spades, so there is no danger of playing in spades. Partner will bid hearts if he has 3 of them.

in the simplest system ever i think that after 1C-1H-1NT:

```
2C =sign-off
2D =sign-off
2H =sign-off
2S =5h,4s 10+
2NT=4h, 10-11
3C =4?h, 4+c, 10-11
3D =5h, 4d, 12+
3H =5h, 10-11
3S =6h,5s FG
3NT=4h, 12+
```

if you want to improve your bidding you should use the CBS(checkback stayman) convention, along with canape-bids.

Comment: The question was about a SAYC-based system; describing how it should be bid in a completely different set of methods isn’t particularly helpful.

And plenty of people manage to bid quite well without taking up canape methods.

Comment: @jl8e how is this bidding NOT SAYC? what is the meaning of 1C-1H-1NT-2S in SAYC?

Comment: New suits are forcing in SAYC. Pretty sure reverses are a game force, as well. I was reading your “simplest system ever” as a different system, which doesn’t appear to be what you meant.

Comment: ok. so 1)what's wrong with bidding 2S? 2) new suits are not always forcing. eg 1H-1S-2C

Comment: New suits by responder are forcing. As for what’s wrong with 2S? You don’t have four spades. Partner’s implied not having 4 of them, but people do bid 1NT on this auction with four, either as a matter of partnership style (which is probably unspecified in SAYC), or because it looks right to deviate. (4333 shapes, or a weak suit) If partner has 4S, you have no way to backpedal. That’s why, when people need to invent a suit, they invent a minor. (Which eventually became systemized as New Minor Forcing.)